# Unit for size returned by mlsd method of FTP class

Tags: python, ftp

I have following snippet.

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp_connect = FTP(link)
ftp_connect.login()
listing = [elem for elem in ftp_connect.mlsd(exact_source_data_path) if elem[0].endswith('.gz')]
```

I am using this snippet to connect to ftp server and fetch list of files and its **facts**. This snipped will return something like this:

```
[('file_1.gz',   {
    'modify': '20171205190142',
    'perm': 'adfr',
    'size': '1556',
    'type': 'file',
    'unique': '41U2B7801',
    'unix.group': '528',
    'unix.mode': '0444',
    'unix.owner': '14'   }),   ('file_2.gz',   {
    'modify': '20171206190136',
    'perm': 'adfr',
    'size': '902254',
    'type': 'file',
    'unique': '41U2B7804',
    'unix.group': '528',
    'unix.mode': '0444',
    'unix.owner': '14'   })]
```

I would like to know what is the unit of the size? Like `size = 1556` Is this in bytes? In KB? The documentation says:

> Return a generator object yielding a tuple of two elements for every
>   file found in path. First element is the file name, the second one is
>   a dictionary containing facts about the file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ftplib.FTP.mlsd](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.mlsd) uses the MLSD command ([RFC 3659](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3659.html)). Its response contains the size in "octets" (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing))), so more likely you "Bytes" then "KB"

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3659.html#section-7.5

Comment: Thanks. Hope I could have found it in documentation of python. :)